# $f \in L^1, g \in L^1$ s.t. $f \cdot g \not \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For what functions for instance stands: $f \in L^1, g \in L^1$ but $f \cdot g$ are not in $L^1$? Thank you

Comment: The 'convolution' tag is confusing because if it the operation is convolution, then $f \ast g \in L^1$. Are you asking for multiplication or convolution?

Comment: I am asking for multiplication. It is connected with definition of convolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thank you. For $g(x)f(x) \in L^1$ so $ \int_0^1 1/x dx = [ln|x|]_0^1 $ how can I set $0$ to x?

Comment: You can't. $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \ln|x| = -\infty$ and that's why $f \cdot g$ is not in $L^1$, which is what you asked for.